# How to Make Readonly to any individual row of a table with php in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Actually i want to make read-only some row in my table of a database .

For Example my table has 3 columns (1.no. (int) , 2. Lenght , 3. Status ) and
6 records (1.['1','512','ok'] , 2.['2','512','ok'] , 3.['3','512','no'] , 4.['4','512','ok'] , 5.['5','512','no'] )

u can see most are same just 3 records are ok and 2 are no those which are ok i need it to make read only means once it status is ok no one can edit that record only read the record.

My script is in PHP and MySQL .

Comment: You should control from within your script whether someone has the privilege to update a record or not, not use MySQL to "lock" rows because it's not MySQL's job, it's your job to determine who can and can't write to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can only lock the tables rather then the rows, so what I suggest you do is create another column called locked which has a 0 or 1 for it's value and do something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET column = X WHERE id = 22 AND locked = 0
```

That would be your best method IMO

Answer (score 1):

A question similar to this one has already been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502298/how-to-set-a-mysql-row-to-read-only).

Essentially, you would create a database trigger for `before_update` and `before_delete`, that identifies the rows that you want to preserve and throws an error if a modification is attempted on said rows.