# How to set a MySQL row to READ-ONLY?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a row in a table that I do not want to be changed (ever).

Is it possible to set a MySQL row to READ-ONLY so that it cannot be updated in any way?  If so, how?

If not, is it possible to set a permanent value in one of the columns of that row so that it cannot be changed?  If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: No, there's no such thing as a read-only row. But you can set up MySQL accounts such that a particular user does not have update/delete permissions.

Comment: Poss dup :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878672/how-to-lock-particular-row-in-mysql

Comment: @Marc B: So neither of the options I mentioned are available?  Please confirm, because the user-permissions solution you mentioned won't solve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: @Kris:  Not a duplicate of that question at all.  My question is entirely different.

Comment: Well, you can mark the table as readonly. So, no updates will occur to table.

Comment: @Rahul: I need to update the other rows in the table, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is likely to be business logic, which probably doesn't belong in your data storage layer.  However, it can nonetheless be accomplished using [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/trigger-syntax.html).

You can create a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that raises an error if a "locked" record is about to be updated; since an error occurs *before* the operation is undertaken, MySQL ceases to proceed with it.  If you also want to prevent the record from being deleted, you'd need to create a similar trigger `BEFORE DELETE`.

To determine whether a record is "locked", you could create a boolean `locked` column:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN locked BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE;

DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER foo_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
IF OLD.locked THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot update locked record';
END IF;;

CREATE TRIGGER foo_del BEFORE DELETE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
IF OLD.locked THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot delete locked record';
END IF;;

DELIMITER ;

UPDATE my_table SET locked = TRUE WHERE ...;
```

Note that [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/signal.html) was introduced in MySQL 5.5.  In earlier versions, you must perform some erroneous action that causes MySQL to raise an error: I often call an non-existent procedure, e.g. with `CALL raise_error;`

---

> I cannot create an additional column on this table, but the row has a unique id in one of the columns, so how would I do this for that scenario?

Again, if you *absolutely must* place this logic in the storage layer—and cannot identify the locked records through any means other than the PK—you *could* hard-code the test into your trigger; for example, to "lock" the record with `id_column = 1234`:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER foo_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
IF OLD.id_column <=> 1234 THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot update locked record';
END IF;;

CREATE TRIGGER foo_del BEFORE DELETE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
IF OLD.id_column <=> 1234 THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot delete locked record';
END IF;;

DELIMITER ;
```

But this is *absolutely horrible* and I would do *almost anything* to avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks for a very interesting solution.  I cannot create an additional column on this table, but the row has a unique id in one of the columns, so how would I do this for that scenario?

Comment: @Programmer: Just test on that `id` in the `IF` statement of the trigger: `IF OLD.column <=> 'unique_id' THEN ...`.

Comment: Now there's an unorthodox solution. I like it. +1 keep in mind though that you can only have one trigger (per event per table) in mysql so if you already have or need one another trigger in the future... you'd have to combine them into one.

Comment: @eggyal:  OK.  Three questions:  1) What is "<=>"? 2) What is "OLD."? 3) What is "DELIMITER;;" ?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Programmer: [`<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) is the `NULL`-safe equality comparison operator; `OLD` and `NEW` are keywords available in triggers which provide access to the affected record's values before/after the operation - see [Trigger Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/trigger-syntax.html); `DELIMITER` specifies a new statement delimiter in order that commands which themselves contain the usual `;` delimiter are treated as a single statement - you can choose character sequences other than `;;` if you prefer.

Comment: @eggyal:  Thanks for the thorough explanation. Could you please edit your answer to include JUST the EXACT syntax I would need for this scenario (assume table is called "Table1" and the unique id column is "uniqueid") so that I can accept your Answer?  I'm just completely unfamiliar with Triggers and their syntax so I don't want to do anything wrong that could negatively affect my Database.  Thanks again!