# php pdo mySQL lock mechanism

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to ask if there is such a function in which the data in the database cannot be edited anymore. I am using php pdo in my server side programming and i am using mySQL database.

The scenario is like this, in my database i have this column called `Flag` the time I add/insert the entries the flag will be `0` when the flag is zero the entries can be manipulated. When a certain criteria is achieved I will have an entry with the flag of `1`, I am doing this by duplicating the entry with the flag of `0`. The new entry flag with the flag is `1`(row), it cannot be manipulated anymore. Meaning it cannot be `Updated`,`Deleted` but it can be search as the data with the flag of `1`.

Comment: You cant lock a row, but you can do something like this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502298/how-to-set-a-mysql-row-to-read-only

Comment: @zdeniiik look promising i didnt think of the read only way